# Defining a sapui5 table

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

Is is possible to define a sapui5 table in html instead of javascript? I want to seperate the presentation layer (html) from the code (javascript).

Comment: You can use HTML views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your table in a view and views can be built either with xml or as a javascript method of an object that gets called in runtime (createContent).

In sapui5 you cannot turn a <table> element into an sapui5 table easily.

Comment: But it is possible to turn a `<table>` element into a sapui5 table?

Comment: Nope. The paradigm of sapui5 is that you let it render the html for you. You tell it that there is a table (either by instantiating a sap.ui.table.Table object explicitly or by typing <table> in an xml file, which does the same thing behind the scenes). You can of course mix hand-coded html with auto-generated portions.

Answer (score -1):

### yes, you can

please refer following code:

```
new sap.m.Table({
  id:"mainViewTbl",
  items:"{/ET_HEADERSet}",
  headerToolbar : [
                  new sap.m.Toolbar({
                  content:[
                           new sap.m.SearchField({
                           placeholder:"{i18n>mainViewSearchField}"
                           })
                           ]
                  })
  ],
  columns:[
          new sap.m.Column({
          header:[
                  new sap.m.Label({
                  text:"{i18n>workOrderNo}"
                  })
                  ]
          }),new sap.m.Column({
          header:[
                  new sap.m.Label({
                  text:"{i18n>orderNo}"
                  })
                  ]
          }),new sap.m.Column({
          header:[
                  new sap.m.Label({
                  text:"{i18n>location}"
                  })
                  ]
          }),new sap.m.Column({
          header:[
                  new sap.m.Label({
                  text:"{i18n>lineEnterDate}"
                  })
                  ]
          }),new sap.m.Column({
          header:[
                  new sap.m.Label({
                  text:"{i18n>operation}"
                  })
                  ]
          })
          ],
  items:[
        new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells:[
               new sap.m.Text({
               text:"{Dname}"
               }),
               new sap.m.Text({
               text:"{Dname}"
               }),
               new sap.m.Text({
               text:"{Dname}"
               }),
               new sap.m.Text({
               text:"{Dname}"
               }),
               new sap.m.Text({
               text:"{Dname}"
               })
               ]
        })
        ]
  })
```